# Convergence of the image of a sequence in topological sense

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I haven't been able to find it, but i'm sure this question has been answered since it is a fundamemtal one:

Let $(X, \tau $) and $(Y, \tau $) be topological spaces. Let $f: X\to Y $ be continuous. If ${x_n}$ is a sequence in X amd $x_n\to x $, then $f(x_n)\to f(x) $

Ok so since f is comtinuous this would mean $f(x_n)$ and $f(x) \in U $ where U is an open set in Y. So is this enough to conclude that $f(x_n) $ is in a nbhd U of $f(x) $ s.t. there exists an N in which all $N \geq n$ means $f(x_n) \in U $ ?   I feel that this isn't sound also i fell that maybe the only way to prove this is might be through contradiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organize your thoughts: we want to prove that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Let $V$ be an open neighbourhood of $f(x)$. Our objective is to find $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_0 \implies f(x_n) \in V$.

Since $f$ is continuous, there is an open neighbourhood of $x$, $U$, such that $f(U) \subset V$. Since $x_n \to x$, we apply the definition of convergence of $x_n$ to the neighbourhood $U$: there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_0 \implies x_n \in U$.

Then $n \geq n_0 \implies f(x_n) \in f(U) \subset V$. In other words, $n \geq n_0 \implies f(x_n) \in V$. But that's what we wanted. Done.

Comment: So because $x_n$ and $x $ $\in U $ continuity allows that open set to be mapped to V in the image space then. Ok. Thanks